# XPath and @XmlPath: same path with different element node name in Java

Tags: java, xpath

I am using in Java the annotation @XmlPath from the org.eclipse.persistence.oxm
I need to map the same field but with different father element node name.
Example:

```
@XmlPath("reports/FATHER1/ReportName/text()")
public void setReportName(String reportName) {
    this.reportName = reportName;
}

@XmlPath("reports/FATHER2/ReportName/text()")
public void setReportName(String reportName) {
    this.reportName = reportName;
}
```

I would like to have only one method setReportName and use a variable expression instead of "FATHER1" or "FATHER2" like:

```
@XmlPath("reports/"takeEveryVariableFatherExpression"/ReportName/text()")
public void setReportName(String reportName) {
    this.reportName = reportName;
}
```

Comment: Could you use a wildcard like `@XmlPath("reports/*/ReportName/text()")` ? Or should it be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

xpath `name` function can be used to compare the node/tag. Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name

You can use `name` function to check if the node/tag contains 'FATHER'.

Your xpath will be - `reports/*[contains(name(),'FATHER')]/ReportName/text()`.

If 'FATHER' is supposed to be at the beginning, then you can also use - `reports/*[starts-with(name(),'FATHER')]/ReportName/text()`.